# Why the order of return type matters when we define a method in Java?

Tags: java, syntax

```
public void static final finalMethod()
{ 

//This throws error saying "Syntax error on token                       
//"void", volatile expected"

}

public static final void finalMethod()
{

}
```

works fine. Why the order plays an important role in defining a method?
Why java expects the volatile keyword here?

Comment: because that was the syntax!

Comment: tldr; The *modifiers* are a separate production than the return type.

Comment: `public synchronized volatile final static strictfp transient void kill_me()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it is how it is designed.

Compiling isn't just magic. It parses the code and specific syntax has to be followed for it to properly interpret it.

Syntax is syntax and that's it.

Rules are made to be imposed. And syntax is a lot like rules. They've to be followed.

I can't get deep into this, like specifications as I'm no java coder. I code C#, but the above applies to *most* compiled languages.

Comment: downvoter, care to elaborate?

Comment: Fairly sure someone just mass downvoted

Comment: You are right that's why one throws an error and the other doesn't, but you're not right to suggest that such constraints on syntax are inherently necessary. There are other languages with much freer syntax.

Comment: @joeln such as...? Also, I used the term *most* and not *all*

Comment: @Rogue There is no such thing as 'mass downvoted' here, short of exploits.

Comment: @EJP pseudo for "downvoted a bunch of answers"

Comment: @Rogue And? If they're wrong they should be downvoted, nu? and upvoted if they're right?

Answer (score 9):

The important thing is that the return type (`void` in this case) must always be the immediately preceding item before the method's name, then the keywords must precede the return type, but the order withing the kewords does not matter.

For instance all these method's declarations are valid:

```
public static final void finalMethod0() {

}

public final static void finalMethod1() {

}

final public static void finalMethod2() {

}

final static public void finalMethod3() {

}

static public final void finalMethod4() {

}

static final public void finalMethod5() {

}
```

Comment: The key point here is that by requiring the type to immediately precede the method name, later versions of Java could invent additional keywords. The current ordering ensures that keywords like static will never be confused with the return type.

Comment: @joeln You are right, but I don't think that, even with new keywords and even with this syntax that enforces the return type before the method's name, will be never legal to create classes named with a keyword name.

Comment: @joeln You're making it up. Either a new keyword is a keyword or it isn't. If it's a keyword it is unambiguous, period.

Answer (score 6):

Because the language specification says so.

See [8.4 Method Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4) which give the grammar

```
MethodDeclaration:
  {MethodModifier} MethodHeader MethodBody

MethodHeader:
  Result MethodDeclarator [Throws] 
  TypeParameters {Annotation} Result MethodDeclarator [Throws]

MethodDeclarator:
  Identifier ( [FormalParameterList] ) [Dims]
```

Answer (score 3):

Refer [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4) for method declaration.

> MethodDeclaration:
>       MethodHeader MethodBody
>
> MethodHeader:
>       MethodModifiersopt TypeParametersopt Result MethodDeclarator Throwsopt
>
> MethodDeclarator:
>       Identifier ( FormalParameterListopt )

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, you threw the type into the middle of all the keywords. You have to specify them by:

```
<keywords> <type> <name>(<arguments>) {}
```

As for *why* this is, I would say that "it is how it is".

Answer (score 0):

You can interchange the modifiers, but the return type must beside the function

example :

```
                public static void main(String args[]){
                }
```

both are same

```
                static public  void main(String args[]){
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

The syntax is defined the way it is (and many answers have pointed to [its definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4)) to:

1. ensure that the Java compiler (and other simpler code analysis tools) can unambiguously and quickly interpret your declaration.
2. ensure that this will be true even as the language develops later on.

Imagine that we lived in a world where the `static` keyword wasn't invented yet, and when reorderings like the one that currently gives a syntax error are valid. Then, arguably, `static` might be a valid name for a Java type (like `int` or `String`). So when some genius eventually invents the keyword `static`, a declaration like:

```
MyType static Foo() {
    ...
}
```

might be ambiguous: is `static` the type or the keyword? By requiring the return type to immediately precede the name of the function, the language is more *future-proof*. Java language extensions can continue to invent keywords, knowing that they'll be safe to be inserted before the return type in the declaration.

Comment: If `static` becomes a new keyword the new language is entirely unambiguous anyway.